# Out of memory in Talend

Tags: talend

I'm still having some problems with this error in `Talend`. I already changed the `VM Argument`s to this:

Arguments:

```
-Xms1024m
-Xms1024m
```

And then I always get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to use "-Xmx" not "-Xms" twice:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms

Comment: Enterprise talend uses -Xmx2G as default. If you're working with large lookups in tMap turn on the file cache. Excel files can be a problem, on talendforge there are some components that worth to check, so you don't become using -Xmx30G :)

Answer (score 0):

[The -Xms option sets the initial and minimum Java heap size](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html)

You increased the initial heap size not the maximum.

[You need to use Xmx like @David Tonhofer said.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms)

If this is not enough you should watch your memory management. Having too much lookup (data volume)in a same subjob or storing big volume of data in tHash can lead to memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally I would suggest to check -XX:MaxPermSize parameter as well. In case of bigger jobs I need to change it to -XX:MaxPermSize=512m